Gitlab clean-up job should run only when certain jobs have run regardless of failure or success
I'm creating a pipeline to test helm charts by linting and checking the chart, packing the helm, installing them on a k8s cluster, run API tests on it and delete everything in the k8s cluster afterwards. I'm currently running into to sub-optimal pipeline flows with the clean-up job. My pipeline is as follows:
stages:
  - helm-checks
  - helm-package
  - build-k8s-test-env
  - tests
  - clean-up-k8s-test-env

helm-lint-template:
  stage: helm-checks

polaris:
  stage: helm-checks

kubescape:
  stage: helm-checks

helm-package:
  stage: helm-package

build-k8s-test-environment:
  stage: build-k8s-test-env
  script: 
    - kubectl create ns $NAMESPACE
    - helm install

hurl-tests:
  stage: tests

clean-up-k8s-test-environment:
  stage: clean-up-k8s-test-env
    - kubectl delete all --all -n $NAMESPACE

I want my pipeline to always clean-up the created k8s environment with the clean-up-k8s-test-environment, but this should only run if the build-k8s-test-environment has run regardless if its successful or not. But the clean-up-k8s-test-environment should only run after the jobs in the tests stage have finished, in case the build was successful. Also, it should not run if the jobs in earlier stages like the helm-checks or helm-package stage have failed.
I've tried using
clean-up-k8s-test-environment:
  stage: clean-up-k8s-test-env
  needs:
    - build-k8s-test-environment
    - hurl-tests
  when: always

But in this example, the clean-up-k8s-test-environment job runs when there is an failure in helm-checks or helm-package, and therefore the clean-up job will also fail as the build-k8s-test-environment will not have run. It seems that if the jobs in the needs have not run, Gitlab falls back to the when: always
Does anyone know a more optimal way I can implement this?
clean-up-k8s-test-environment:
stage: clean-up-k8s-test-env
needs:
- build-k8s-test-environment
- hurl-tests
when: always

This doesn't look to be on-topic on SO, mostly suitable on Devops

Why not just add the --ignore-not-found flag to your delete command?  Then you could use the when: always key in the cleanup job

@ha36d
Thank you for your suggestion. Based on your tips I created the following gitlab-ci:
stages:
  - helm-checks
  - helm-package
  - tests

helm-lint-template:
  stage: helm-checks

polaris:
  stage: helm-checks

kubescape:
  stage: helm-checks

helm-package:
  stage: helm-package

build-k8s-test-environment:
  stage: tests
  script: 
    - kubectl create ns $NAMESPACE
    - helm install
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    on_stop: stop_review
    auto_stop_in: 1 hour

hurl-tests:
  stage: tests
  needs:
  - build-k8s-test-environment


clean-up-k8s-test-environment:
  stage: tests
    - kubectl delete all --all -n $NAMESPACE
  needs:
    - build-k8s-test-environment
    - hurl-tests
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
    action: stop


What I've added is the needs to the clean-up-k8s-test-environment as this job should run after the other jobs in the same stage have finished. I removed the manual part, as I want this to be completely automatic to not hamper development time where the engineer has to manually delete the environment every time. Also adjusted the environment name purely on personal preferences.
This setup indeed causes that a failure in helm-checks does indeed not trigger the tests stage, therefore not running the clean-up-k8s-test-environment job. The downside is that a failure in the hurl-tests job will not trigger the clean-up-k8s-test-environment. I experimented with the on_failure: true setting in the hurl-tests job, but that allows merge requests to be merged with failed tests in it.
For now I've set my mind to change my setup to not delete a feature environment in every pipeline, but only delete the environment if a feature branch is merged. I will create a Kubernetes namespace one time only and check and skip the creation of it, if it already exists. Will do the same with the helm chart, if it's already in the environment, delete it before building it again. All in the build job.
This is not the ideal setup, but will do for now.
So now I have
build-k8s-test-environment:
  stage: tests
  script: 
    - kubectl delete all --all -n $KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE --ignore-not-found
    - kubectl delete ns $KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE --ignore-not-found
    - helm install --namespace $KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE --create-namespace


What about the allow_failure for gitlab ci. Would that be helpfull?

Thanks for the suggestion, but in my use-case that was not optimal due to the possibility to merge pipelines with allow_failures.

The solution is to use Gitlab Environments and deployments:
I have set it up for merge request, but can be changed to main/master/feature branches.
I have put all the jobs of build-k8s-test-environment, hurl-tests and clean-up-k8s-test-environment in one stage (tests) because of what has been explained here.
In build-k8s-test-environment, an environment is created that exists until

someone stop the environment manually in the interface
when the merge request is merged or closed
after 1 hour (to do it anyway automatically if the merge request is not merged or closed after 1 hour but we need to execute the cleanup)

.gitlab-ci.yml:
stages:
  - helm-checks
  - helm-package
  - tests

helm-lint-template:
  stage: helm-checks

polaris:
  stage: helm-checks

kubescape:
  stage: helm-checks

helm-package:
  stage: helm-package

build-k8s-test-environment:
  stage: tests
  script: 
    - kubectl create ns $NAMESPACE
    - helm install
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    on_stop: stop_review
    auto_stop_in: 1 hour
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID

hurl-tests:
  stage: tests

clean-up-k8s-test-environment:
  stage: tests
    - kubectl delete all --all -n $NAMESPACE
  environment:
    name: review/$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    action: stop
  rules:
    - if: $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_ID
      when: manual

